Is resteasy-core removed/missing in keycloak 24.0.X?
I try to follow the tutorial by baeldung to setup a keycloak server app. But when I update the version for keycloak to 24.0.X the jboss resteasy-core lib is missing and so I can't use the ResteasyContext class. I removed the folder in my m2 repo to reload the packages etc. but nothing worked. When I add the dependency for resteasy-core itself, the application is starting but instant shutting down:
2024-05-11T17:44:11.062+02:00  INFO 61341 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-05-11T17:44:11.064+02:00  INFO 61341 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-05-11T17:44:11.065+02:00  INFO 61341 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52750', transport: 'socket'

I don’t think that version of KeyCloak uses RESTEasy.

Yes RESTEasy was removed.
See #27406 JavaDocs generation broken after removal of resteasy-core

How should I use resteasy with keycloak 24 so? Which dependency should I add to replace this remove and make it works?

Have you tried org.keycloak.broker.provider.util.SimpleHttp?
